# How to find this Linear transformation?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

IF given that $$T:V_3\rightarrow V_3$$ Such that
$T(0,1,2)=T(3,1,2)$ and  $T(1,1,1)=T(2,2,2,)$

Find the Linear Transformation $T$

Do i first need to add a Linearly Independent vector to the set $S={(0,1,2),(1,1,1)}$ to find the basis ? and after that show the new set $S'$ as Basis of $V_3$ and then proceed in usual manner ?

Comment: $T$ is linear, so $T(0,1,2)=T(3,1,2)$ is equivalent to $T((0,1,2)-(3,1,2))=0$.

Comment: Asking for "the" linear transformation might be confusing. Without further restrictions, more than one unique transformation exist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Christoph has mentioned in the comments, your assumptions imply that
$$
T(3,0,0) = 0 \qquad T(1,1,1) = 0
$$
Hence,
$$
T(1,0,0) = \frac{1}{3}T(3,0,0) = 0\qquad T(0,1,1) = T(1,1,1) - T(1,0,0) = 0
$$
Hence $T(0,1,0) = -T(0,0,1)$. Let $v = T(0,1,0)$, then
$$
T(x,y,z) = xT(1,0,0) + yT(0,1,0) + zT(0,0,1) = 0+yv -zv = (y-z)v
$$